# How to delete an existing payment link in instamojo through api?

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, instamojo

In my laravel application, i usually create a payment link through instamojo and send it via emails. I need a provision to cancel the payment in my application. But since the payment link is already there for the user through email, I want to suspend the payment url. So how should i do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that through their API.

If the client already paid, you should issue a refund - https://docs.instamojo.com/docs/creating-a-refund